# Remove one Frameset Completely and merge that Frameset HTML files into 1 HTML file

Tags: html, frameset

I have this `MainFrame.html` file, in this HTML file I have to remove

`<frameset cols="20%,80%*" id="frameSet1" >`

completely and also have to merge its 2 HTML files into 1 HTML file.

//MainFrame.html (Note: This is the complete HTML code)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>abc</title>
<script src="./resourceFiles/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css"></style></head>

<frameset rows="80,*" id="frameSet0" >
<frame src="./resourceFiles/showTopFrame.htm" >

<frameset cols="20%,80%*" id="frameSet1" >
<frame src="./resourceFiles/showLeftNav.htm" name="menu" >
<frame src="./resourceFiles/content.htm" name="information" >
</frameset>
</frameset>

</html>
```

As it is clearly mentioned in above code we have two frame source :

```
<frame src="./resourceFiles/showLeftNav.htm" name="menu" >
<frame src="./resourceFiles/content.htm" name="information" >
```

So, here I have to merge above dynamically created HTML files say `showLeftNav.htm` and `content.htm` into one HTML file.

OR we can Say, I want to display above two HTML files in lower frame.

**Note: The complete web page should be divided into 2 rows only.**

Comment: Anything specific you're having problems with? Or, if you want general advice on the matter: don't use frames! [They're obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset).

Comment: This is specific problem, I am working on an application that contains this code and there **cols** pages are generating dynamically so I can't merge them using hard code.

Comment: I am new here, please let me know If I need to provide any other information.